# Write a query in SQL to display the details of the current job for those employees who worked as a Sales Representative in the past

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Table - 
job_history

```
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
| EMPLOYEE_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE   | JOB_ID     | DEPARTMENT_ID |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
|         102 | 2001-01-13 | 2006-07-24 | IT_PROG    |            60 |
|         101 | 1997-09-21 | 2001-10-27 | AC_ACCOUNT |           110 |
|         101 | 2001-10-28 | 2005-03-15 | AC_MGR     |           110 |
|         201 | 2004-02-17 | 2007-12-19 | MK_REP     |            20 |
|         114 | 2006-03-24 | 2007-12-31 | ST_CLERK   |            50 |
|         122 | 2007-01-01 | 2007-12-31 | ST_CLERK   |            50 |
|         200 | 1995-09-17 | 2001-06-17 | AD_ASST    |            90 |
|         176 | 2006-03-24 | 2006-12-31 | SA_REP     |            80 |
|         176 | 2007-01-01 | 2007-12-31 | SA_MAN     |            80 |
|         200 | 2002-07-01 | 2006-12-31 | AC_ACCOUNT |            90 |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Can you please share a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following using a sub-select to get the current / last job and `EXISTS` to check if the employee worked as a sales representative in the past:

```
SELECT jh.* 
FROM job_history jh INNER JOIN (
  SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, MAX(START_DATE) AS START_DATE 
  FROM job_history 
  GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID
) cj ON jh.EMPLOYEE_ID = cj.EMPLOYEE_ID AND jh.START_DATE = cj.START_DATE
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM job_history
  WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = jh.EMPLOYEE_ID AND JOB_ID = 'SA_REP' AND START_DATE < jh.START_DATE
)
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5a9975f09f04555b0bcc9c1662903d1f)